# Powerbuilder: insert a string into a rich text control

Tags: powerbuilder, rte

I have a string LS_STRING that contains an aggregated code that I wish to display within a rich text control.

```
string ls_string = "abc123"

rte_display.clear() // to clear any previous text...
rte_display.pasteRTF(ls_string) // to copy whatever my variable contains into the RTE...
rte_display.setredraw (true) // to refresh the view of the control...
```

When I compile the code, it does not produce any error, but also does not produce the expected results. Any hints on how to do this? Thanks!

> > > > > Edit:

Did as suggested, but got the same result: the value of the variable is not pasted into the RTE control...

[image]

```
long ll_number
string ls_number

if isnumber(sle_test.text) then
    ll_number = long(sle_test.text)
    ls_number = string(ll_number, "00000000")
    MESSAGEBOX("VALUE", LS_NUMBER)

    rte_test.setredraw (false)
    rte_test.selecttextall()
    rte_test.clear()
    rte_test.pastertf(ls_number)
    rte_test.setredraw (true)

end if
```

Comment: Version of PowerBuilder? Rich Text control has changed several times.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, make sure that your property DisplayOnly is set to false first.

https://docs.appeon.com/pb2019r2/application_techniques/ch16s03.html#d0e11604

```
string ls_richtext = anyRichText


// Prevent flicker
rte_1.SetRedraw(FALSE) 

// Replace the old text with text for the current row
rte_1.SelectTextAll()
rte_1.Clear()
rte_1.PasteRTF(ls_richtext)
rte_1.SetRedraw(TRUE)
```

If this doesnt work, perhaps it is your richText that needs to be looked at?